# Firebase FCM InternalServerError

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented Firebase FCM in my app about a month ago, and it has worked great ever since, until today. When I am trying to send a push notification from my console, nothing ever shows up. I find this very strange considering it worked before I went to bed yesterday. I do also have a PHP script that sends push notifications (FCM) as well, which also was working - but when I try to use this to send a push notification, I get this:

`{"multicast_id":5593178441415796544,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InternalServerError"}]}`

I find this very strange. I Googled this, and I read something about re-generating my APNS certificates (because they might be wrong or something), which I thought was weird as well, due to the fact that I created new certificates yesterday as well (which was working). Now I have once again tried to delete, and generate new - without any luck.

I also want to point out that when I go to my 'Cloud messaging' tab in Firebase, to configure my certificates, I am unable to delete - only re-upload.

What could this possibly be? I have checked my certificates and my API key is correct. It was working 100% 10 hours ago.

Could this be a Firebase problem, or how would I solve this? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you're positive that nothings wrong with your implementation or something disruptive with your connection that maybe causing thw error, I suggest contacting Firebase Support for further help.

Comment: I am getting the same InternalServerError for 3-4 days. Sometimes I get success but generally, it is crashing. When I directly post to fcm without my implementation, I am getting the same error.

Comment: @uplaoder33 I see. I have contacted Firebase regarding this issue, and I am still waiting for a response. Glad to hear that I am not the only one affected by this. I'll keep you updated!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue using only FCM for Android. Anyway the push notification is arriving 3 or 5 minutes later.

Comment: Getting the same error.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the `InternalServerError` returned by FCM before February 2017,
were due to issues with the APNs certificates.

The API has now been updated.
Now if there an issue with the APNs certificate,
FCM will return `error:InvalidApnsCredential`

Comment: Just received today. Also when sending to IOS {
    "multicast_id": 8747014403719096755,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "InternalServerError"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: I'm also getting it today. Works fine on my development phone but not to my production phones/users. same error as ^

Comment: Once again today - hang for 11 seconds, than this error (to Android)